# LESS : hue, saturation and lightness - how to use?

Tags: css, colors, less

Trying LESS for a few days. Came with a problem with HSL - Hue-Saturation-Lightness, or may be it's a problem of my understanding, I'm afraid.

I tried the following HTML:

```
<div class="box hue">1</div>&nbsp;<div class="box saturation">2</div>&nbsp;<div class="box lightness">3</div>
```

And tried the LESS accordingly:

```
   @color2: #167e8a;
    .hue{
      background-color: hue(@color2);
    }

    .saturation{
      background-color: saturation(@color2);
    }

    .lightness{
      background-color: lightness(@color2);
    }


    .box{
      width: 50px;
      height: 20px;
    }
```

But the first three classes showing empty, doesn't showing anything - no background color. But the box is taking width & height.

What Photoshop did for me:
[image: Color and HSL - Photoshop did for me]

I checked the color code in Photoshop with changes in HSL, they all showing different colors in different combination. Then why my LESS is deceiving me?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

HSL LESS functions don't return a color, rather an integer value for the color *part* that the name indicates.

From the [documentation](http://lesscss.org/#usage):

```
hue(@color); // returns the `hue` channel of @color in the HSL space
```

## Examples

```
.foo{
    color: hue(#167e8a);
}

// rendered as
.foo {
  // invalid...hence you don't see a color
  color: 186;
}
```

Before going further, it's worth mentioning that the [spin() function](http://lesscss.org/functions/#color-operations-spin) will modify hue without requiring that you break down the color parts. Specifically, it will "rotate the hue angle of a color in either direction."

Even if you wish to break down HSL manually, it is straightforward.

```
@h: hue(#167e8a);
@s: saturation(#167e8a);
@l: lightness(#167e8a);

.foo{
    color: hsl(@h,@s,@l);  
}

// rendered as
.foo {
  color: #167d88;
}
```

More importantly, you can take the extracted channels, modify them, and subsequently rebuild the color:

```
@h: hue(#167e8a) + 40;
@s: saturation(#167e8a) - 5;
@l: lightness(#167e8a) + 30;

.foo{
    color: hsl(@h,@s,@l);  
}

// rendered as
.foo {
  color: #5978de;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. But I also asked "How to use HSL in LESS?". Suppose, I want to make a new color from the base one (#167e8a) with a HSL combination accordingly of (+24)-(-25)-(-56). How can I achieve this?

Comment: Look at the last example...you can add an offset to each of those values which you extract. Does that answer the question?

Comment: Exactly. That's exactly what I's expecting. Thank you so much for assisting me though the journey.